# How to create a checkbox in the header of QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, checkbox, qtablewidget

I need to create a table like this. When I check the checkbox in the header, all the checkboxes in the same column will be automatically checked. How can I create the checkbox in the header and how can I set signal-slot for that check box?

This is my old code:

```
ui.table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
ui.table->verticalHeader()->hide();
ui.table->setRowCount(8);
ui.table->setColumnCount(3);
ui.table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << tr(" ") << tr("Interger") << tr("String"));

for (int i = 0; tableindb.size() > i; i++){
    myconstruct ptv = tableindb.value(i);
    QTableWidgetItem *itemCheckbox = new QTableWidgetItem(" ");
    itemCheckbox->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    ui.table->setItem(i, 0, itemCheckbox);
    itemCheckbox->setData(Qt::ItemDataRole::UserRole, ptv.usercheck);

    QTableWidgetItem *itemNumber = new QTableWidgetItem("Integer");
    itemNumber->setData(Qt::ItemDataRole::DisplayRole, ptv.usernumber);
    ui.table->setItem(i, 1, itemNumber);

    QTableWidgetItem *itemName = new QTableWidgetItem("String");
    itemName->setData(Qt::ItemDataRole::DisplayRole, ptv.username);
    ui.table->setItem(i, 2, itemName);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is [`QTableWidget::setHorizontalHeaderItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setHorizontalHeaderItem) what you're looking for?

Comment: @G.M.: No, I tried `QTableWidgetItem* checkbox = new QTableWidgetItem(" ");
 checkbox->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
 ui.tableBereitstehende->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, checkbox);`. But it does not work.

Comment: Ok.  Possible dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542803/how-to-implement-checkbox-in-header-of-qtreeview)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement checkbox in header of QtreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542803/how-to-implement-checkbox-in-header-of-qtreeview)